# Vuetify Select with Vuex getters

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am using Vuex and I have a getter that returns an array. I am using this array in a vuetify drop down select. I need to add an additional property at the first of the array. When I do this I only get a number returned from my computed property.

here is my code:

Vuetify Select:

```
<v-select
 v-on:change="setGame"
 v-model="gameid"
 :items="games"
 item-text="gametitle"
 item-value="gid"
 label="Select Game"
 ></v-select>
```

Computed Property:

```
games(){
    return this.$store.getters.games.unshift({ 'gametitle': 'All Games', gid: null });
}
```

Original return statement which works fine
`return this.$store.getters.games`

Error:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Number with value 3.

found in

---> <VSelect>
       <VToolbar>
         <Navbar> at src/components/layout/Navbar.vue
           <VApp>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. I need to use concat in stead of push. here is my final code:

```
games(){
    var selectAllGames = [
        {'gametitle': 'All Games', gid: null}
    ]
    return selectAllGames.concat(this.$store.getters.games);
}
```